# Is it possible to upload a file (mainly media) on mongodb and then get a download link to that file which can be shared among different users?

Tags: mongodb

Basically im trying to implement a chat project for learning purposes. I have implemented everything only the feature to send/receive files is left. I was thinking of uploading the file to mongodb then sharing the download link to all the users in the chat group. I don't know how to implement it. I tried searching but didn't find exactly what I wanted.

Im using nodejs at backend and angular at front end.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you save the content of the file in MongoDB, you will not be able to generate a link to the file using MongoDB.

If you want to generate a 'public link' via which anyone can access the file, maybe upload it to S3 and generate a link.

Or, you can create an API in NodeJS, which returns the content of the file from MongoDB, given the ID of the file.
Example: `/api/file/:id`
So if you access `/api/file/6197593befeb8915cad457ff` will return the file with ID `6197593befeb8915cad457ff`.